# Scrape value of checked input radio button

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to get value of checked input in scrapy. Tried variations of input:checked, input[checked=checked] among other but cannot get it work...

```
    tonersave =response.xpath('/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/form[1]/div[4]/dl[1]/dd[1]/div[1]/label/input[@checked=checked]/text()').extract()

    <dt>
Toner Save
</dt>
<dd>
<div>
<label class="radioSimple">
<input type="radio" name="B17" value="100"  checked="checked" />
Off
</label>
<label class="radioSimple">
<input type="radio" name="B17" value="0" />
On
</label>
</div>
</dd>
```

Answer (score 0):

found it..this works...

```
/input[@checked="checked"]/@value').extract()
```

Comment: now do it as css selector please